# Bonjour services sniffer code

Tags: objective-c, bonjour, zeroconf

Is there a library or open sourced Obj C code that will let me sniff for all advertised  Bonjour services on a network? Best if it works on Mac OS X or iOS.

Thx all.

Answer (score 4):

You're spoilt for choice.

OS X ships with the `mdns` command for registering and browsing services on the link-local network. To browse for advertised websites (normally services of type `_http._tcp.`) you'd do this:

```
mdns -B _http._tcp
```

And a list will return and update pretty much instantly as things appear/disappear. Yes, it's [open-sourced](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/mDNSResponder/mDNSResponder-320.5/). Apple's C-based implementation of multicast DNS (both library and tools) compiles without much hassle on most *NIXes.

If you're looking for a GUI tool, I find the [bonjour browser](http://www.tildesoft.com/) app from Tildesoft pretty useful.

If you don't want to use `mdns` to advertise your own services try the [network beacon](http://www.chaoticsoftware.com/ProductPages/NetworkBeacon.html).

Comment: No worries. If you mark the question as answered you'll get more responses in future.